# mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect] Error

Tags: php, mysql

mysql_connect is throwing an error on my clients page [Here](http://www.virkoh.com/our-client.php)

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'virkoh_com_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\virkoh.com\httpdocs\config.php on line 16
Couldn't make connection.
```

I need to know what exactly went wrong and how to rectify it. . .please help me out guys

```
<?php
include "config.php";
session_set_cookie_params(0);
$_SESSION['user']=1;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['company_name'] == "" && $_POST['name'] == "" && $_POST['phone'] == "" && $_POST['email'] == "" && $_POST['message'] ==""){
        $error = "Please enter your companyname, name, phone number, email address and your enquiry message";
    }else{
        $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
        $name =$_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $to = 'info@virkoh.com';
        $detail='Company Name:'.$_POST['company_name'].'<br>Name:'.$_POST['name'].'<br> Phone Number:'.$_POST['phone'].'<br> Email Address:'.$_POST['email'];
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <info@virkoh.com>' . "\r\n";
        $message = '<br> Enquiry:'. $_POST['message'];
        $str_mail = "Dear Sir / Madam, <br> Thanks for contacting Virkoh Facility Management Services. We will revert back to you regarding your requirement at the earliest.We look forward to meet you soon.'<br><br>' With Best Regards, .<br> Admin<br>Email Address: info@virkoh.comWebsite: www.virkoh.com";
        //$mailsend=mail($to,$detail,$str_comments);
        //var_dump($mailsend);
        // to check whether the mail is sent or not mail($email, "Acknowledgement from Virkoh Facility Management Services",'<br>'.$str_mail, $headers);
        mail($to, "Shankar <info@virkoh.com>!", $detail.'<br>'.$message, $headers);
        $result = mysql_query("insert into feedbackvirkoh(company_name,name,phone,email,message) values ('$company_name','$name','$phone','$email','$message')") or die("SQL execution erroryyy : ".mysql_error());
        //header("Location:welcome.php");
        //echo '<script>alert("Thanks for contacting Virkoh Facility Management Services."); </script>';
    }
}
?>
```

my config.php File below:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();


//demo hosting username and password.....

    define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "virkoh_com_userr"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS","virkoh123@#"); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","virkoh_com_virkoh_3"); // set database name

define ("COOKIE_TIME_OUT", 10); //specify cookie timeout in days (default is 10 days)
define ('SALT_LENGTH', 9);

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","'virkoh_com_user","***") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db("virkoh_com_virkoh_3", $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT|E_NOTICE));?>
```

Comment: Think the message is clear. Your user has no permission to access the database.

Comment: Just a tip change your usernames/passwords in your code before posting them.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in this line, there's an extra apostrophe in the username.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","'virkoh_com_user","***") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
                                   ^
```

You should use the constants that you defined earlier:

```
$line = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");
```

Comment: I didn't look at the rest, since it doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: Usually for what are the reasons does this error show up. please name it

Comment: I just told you. The username or password are wrong. What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR virkoh_com_user@localhost` show?